# How should I verify this $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup=\infty \hspace{3pt}\text{and} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf=0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$x_n:=\begin{cases}n & n\hspace{3pt}\text{is odd} \\ \frac{-1}{n} & n\hspace{3pt}\text{is even}\end{cases}$$

**Q1**: I know $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup=\infty \hspace{3pt}\text{and} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf=0 $ but I have difficulty to verify this in plain language. Would it be sufficient to say both odd and even number is unbounded so it be?
I belive if I cannot say it in plain language, it must have some points I missed out in my understanding.

**Q2**:Is this justification looks good? This sequence is unlike the regular sequence with limits exists because one is strictly positive goes to infinity contrary the other is strictly negative and converges to $0$

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Find a convergent subsequence for $\lim\inf$ and a monotonic increasing divergent subsequece for the $\lim\sup$

Answer (score 1):

The limit infimum is defined as
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}{x_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\inf_{m \geq n}{x_m})
$$
If you consider $y_n =\inf_{m \geq n}{x_m}$ you get that
$$
y_n=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{-1}{n+1} & n\;\text{odd} \\
      \frac{-1}{n} & n\;\text{even}
   \end{cases}
$$
We can see that
$
\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n=0
$
, thus proving that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}x_n=0$. The same idea can be used to show the limit supremum is $\infty$

In plain language this is saying that if I consider all elements of the sequence past a point $n$, their infimum will be  $y_n$, and as $n$ tends to $\infty$, this infimum tends to $0$